# HTML input field height different in different browsers

Tags: html, css

#### Current Situation

On a simple website I have an input control with a fix height where I have a text with a certain font size. I want that text to show up vertically aligned in the middle of the input field. But even though I used a reset css (link [here](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)) and setting the `-webkit-appearance` to `none` it still is not centered.

[image]

You can see that for IE the padding at the top is higher, for iOS it is even worse. There are 12 more pixels padding.

#### Some Code

HTML:

```
<!-- time -->
<input type="text" class="meeting-time" style="-webkit-appearance: none; padding: 0px; inn" value="00:00"/>
```

CSS:

```
.meeting-time {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 37px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "roboto",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 37px;    
    font-weight: 300;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

#### Actual Question

How can I have a text field where the text is vertically aligned for all browsers.

I know this has been asked a couple of times already, but the solutions proposed didn't work until now. It's probably something trivial that I miss.

Comment: *If* the situation is the same a some years ago, then there might be no way. What I remember from formatting forms is that you can only ever get so close to have it look the same across browsers...

Comment: What version of iOS are you using ie device information and Safari version.

Comment: have you tried with any google font ? may be this is fonts rendering issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Took @scooterlord's advice about removing height and it fixed 90% of the problem. The 10% was still that 4px offset using iOS which was the same issue with my first solution. The difference is, with height no longer specified, I was able to add 4px padding-top to align iOS and it wasn't pushing the font on the desktop browsers. So basically:

> 1. Remove height
> 2. Add `padding-top: 4px;`

**See Snippet 2 and/or [<kbd>CODEPEN</kbd>](http://codepen.io/01/pen/bqZmKJ?editors=1100)**

---

**OLD**

There were some changes that were more for aesthetics than for cross-browser compatibilty of the changes that have significant importance they are denoted with a `/* ✎ */`.  Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE. I tried my iPhone 5, but I lost my patience trying to navigate to this page (I have 5 left thumbs )

**IE11**
[image: IE11]
**SNIPPET 1**

```css
html {
  /* ✎ */
  font: 300 16px/1.428 "roboto", sans-serif;
  /* ✎ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  /* ✎ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ✎ */
  margin: 0;
  /* ✎ */
  padding: 0;
  /* ✎ */
  border: 0;
}

.meeting-time {
  width: 100px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  /* ✎ */
  font: inherit;
  /* ✎ */
  font-size: 2.3125rem;
  /* ✎ */
  line-height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  /* ✎ */
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">


<input type="text" class="meeting-time" style="-webkit-appearance: none; padding: 0px;" value="00:00" />
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```css
html {
  /* ✎ */
  font: 300 16px/1.428 "roboto", sans-serif;
  /* ✎ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  /* ✎ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* ✎ */
  margin: 0;
  /* ✎ */
  padding: 0;
  /* ✎ */
  border: 0;
}


/* For iOS BEGIN */


/* ✎ */

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=tel],
input[type=url],
input[type=search] {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* For iOS  END */


/* For demo (optional) BEGIN */

main {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2vh 2vw;
}

header {
  display: table;
}

hgroup {
  display: table-row;
}

h5 {
  text-align: right;
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 150px;
}

h6 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  font: inherit;
}

hr {
  height: 0;
  margin: 1.25em auto;
  border: 0 none transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

hr:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}


/* For demo (optional) END */


/* Example 1 */

.ex1Time {
  width: 100px;
  height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 37px;
  background: yellow;
}


/* Example 2 */

.ex2Time {
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 2.3125rem;
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 4px;
}


/* Example 3 */

.ex3Time {
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 2.3125rem;
  background: yellow;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet'>

<main>

  <hr/>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <h6>Original Code</h6>
      <h5>Example 1</h5>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
  <hr/>

  <input type="text" class="ex1Time" value="00:00">

  <input type="text" class="ex1Time" value="07:22">

  <input type="text" class="ex1Time" value="11:11">

  <input type="text" class="ex1Time" value="12:34">

  <hr/>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <h6 style='display:table-row'>Font dependent lengths are measured in ch units</h6>
      <h6 style='display:table-row;width:400px'>4 inputs Within .ex2Align</h6>
      <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
      <h5>Example 2</h5>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
  <hr/>


  <input type="text" class="ex2Time" value="00:00">

  <input type="text" class="ex2Time" value="07:22">

  <input type="text" class="ex2Time" value="11:11">

  <input type="text" class="ex2Time" value="12:34">


  <hr/>
  <header>
    <hgroup>
      <h6 style='display:table-row'>Using Arial instead of Roboto</h6>
      <h6 style='display:table-row;width:400px'>4 inputs Within .ex3Align</h6>
      <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
      <h5>Example 3</h5>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
  <hr/>


  <input type="text" class="ex3Time" value="00:00">

  <input type="text" class="ex3Time" value="07:22">

  <input type="text" class="ex3Time" value="11:11">

  <input type="text" class="ex3Time" value="12:34">


  <hr/>
</main>
```

Comment: It's definitely better than before. It works perfectly for the browsers that you mentioned, but only after I replaced the Adobe Typekit font (Roboto) with the Google Font (Roboto) as you showed. Still, it looks like that for iOS (10.2) there is a small gap of 4 px above the text. (just FYI: here is the current dev version of the site I'm working on (including your changes): [link](http://time-zone-dev.azurewebsites.net/) )

Comment: Forget about the comment regarding Typekit vs Google Font. The Typekit font was loaded after the css. That's why all the styles were overridden. For Google Fonts this is not an issue. Still, the issue with the 4 px above the text for iOS remains.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the combination of the input field's `height` attribute in combination with the font. Removing the `height` properly centers the text inside the input field.

This is probably due to the fact that there are characters that grow beneath the 00:00 baseline, like for example letters p,q,etc, so the vertical center of the font is below the "00:00" vertical center. The font size includes the boundaries that expand on top of the font size. Check the top and bottom bearing lines in the image below:

[image]

As a solution I would remove the height and use a font-size that produces a total of the wanted height.

Also as a side-note, a 37px input field also includes 2px of border-size (1px top border and 1px bottom border) so using a 35px font-size would be more appropriate to your example.

Comment: You are spot on about removing the height, but the font-family doesn't seem to be a problem if using a unit that's relative to the font like rem, or ch or ex (guessing on the last two,) unless it's got crazy de/ascenders. +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using line-height?

```css
.meeting-time {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 37px;
    line-height:37px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "roboto",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 37px;    
    font-weight: 300;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="meeting-time" style="-webkit-appearance: none; padding: 0px; inn" value="00:00"/>
```

I added line-height to your CSS. Try the above and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work either. Sorry, didn't mention it in my question.

Comment: Line height breaks input fields in android browsers

Answer (score 0):

Remove your height and using padding instead but with ems