# Textbox's width and height is reduced by IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

In the IE11 developer tools, the layout has the width and height of the text box different from the code

[image: IE11]

In the code the width and height properties are set to `width:196` and `height:22`. However, IE11 computes it differently, width=192 and height=16 as shown in the above picture. On the contrary, the height and width are computed exactly the same as in the code by IE9 which is `width:196` and `height:22`. See the picture below.

[image: IE9]

Also, the padding and border are computed differently in IE11.
The HTML code is rendered as expected in IE9 but in IE11, the textbox moves leftwards. Why? How can I make the same code run in IE11 without turning on the compatibility mode?

The application is IE9 compatible, trying to run it on IE11 but facing such display issues.

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xxxx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 0;"">
            <pre>
                <span style="font-size:12pt;color:black;height:13">
                    <label style="position:absolute;left:180;top:312;">    Aaaaaaax  N/A  Baaaaaa:                         (+/-) (Kxx.)</label>
                </span>
                <span style=";font-size:12pt;color:black;background-color:white;height:15;text-align:right">
                    <input name=XX type=text value="#0.00" maxlength=19 title="XX" style="position:absolute;left:420;top:309;width:196;font-size:12pt;color:black;height:22;text-align:right"></input>
                </span>
            </pre>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The answer to which my question is tagged for duplicate doesn't answer why the width of the textbox is reduced in IE11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML input field height different in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682530/html-input-field-height-different-in-different-browsers)

Comment: @Code_Ninja Thanks for looking at my question. However, the post you pointed to doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This should definitely solve your issue, as the issue mentioned in both the questions is same. This is an issue that is already solved by many developers. Search for it, even Google can answer you this.